# Magento - changes to template file not showing up - /customer/form/register.phml

Tags: magento, php

I'm making some changes to /customer/form/register.phml but they are not showing up in the frontend. Changes that I made to login.phtml and forgotpassword.phtml do show up.

I checked if magento was using a fallback from the base/default theme but it's not. I deleted register.phtml in both my theme and in the base/default theme to check what would happen: the page showed up just fine (without the changes of course).

I looks like magento gets the file from somewhere else (maybe the core). I've got no idea on how to solve this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**My Customer.xml file looks like this, I'm using magento 1.5.1**

```
<customer_account_create translate="label">
   <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label>

   <remove name="right"/>
   <remove name="left"/>

   <reference name="root">
       <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>

   <reference name="content">
           <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register"  template="customer/form/register.phtml">
               <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                   <label>Form Fields Before</label>
               </block>
           </block>
   </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Comment: Make sure cacheing is off

Answer (score 4):

The best way to debug this - is to turn on template path hints.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to edit `template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`.

Comment: I used template path to discover a plugin replaced the file. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

Yes i agree with WebFlake turn on template hints that will let you know which template file the form is being pulled from, most likely you are modifying the wrong template.

Here is a link which explains how to turn on template hints: http://vimeo.com/1067069

Comment: Thanks for the video! If I knew this before it could have saved me quite some time!

Comment: +1 cause I just gave remy credit for your video link.

Answer (score 2):

Use the template hints. Also, with any phtml changes you make, make sure that you have caching disabled, and flush all caches (System -> Cache Management).

Answer (score 2):

I used template hints and discovered a plugin replaced the file. Enabling template hints:  http://vimeo.com/1067069 helped a lot

Comment: +1 for actually providing some resource that shows how the F you do this in magento's convoluted system. Could have saved time to just say system->config - switch to main website - click developer, then choose debug and turn template path hints on. I personally hate watching unnecessarily long, slow moving videos to do simple things. Thanks anyhow